# PHP foreach form displaying a 3 sets of array in order

Tags: php, arrays, loops, foreach

I have this form that have an "add field" function. When the add field is triggered/clicked a new set of price[],pax[] and days[] will be added it will became an array.

My question is, is there anyway or is it possible to have an outcome like this when I clicked the submit button? to display them in this order?

```
    price[0] - pax[0] - days[0]
    price[1] - pax[1] - days[1]
    price[2] - pax[2] - days[2]
```

I tried this but it worked only for [0] and did not work on the rest [1] and [2]. PHP

```
    foreach()   {
        // echo here [0]
        foreach()   {
            // echo here [1]
            foreach()   {
                // echo here [2]
            }
        }
    }
```

Here is my code below.

```
    <div>
        <form method="post">
            <div class="" id="buildyourForm">
                <input name="price[]" type="number">
                <select name="pax[]">
                    <option value="2">2</value>
                    <option value="3">3</value>
                    <option value="4">4</value>
                </select>
                <select name="days[]">
                    <option value="2">2 days</option>
                    <option value="3">3 days</option>
                    <option value="4">4 days</option>
                </select>

                <input type="submit" name="submit">

                <div>
                    <input type="button" id="add_field">
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
```

Jquery/Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#add_field").click(function() {
        var lastField = $("#buildyourform div:last");
        var intId = (lastField && lastField.length && lastField.data("idx") + 1) || 2;
        var fieldWrapper = $("<div id=\"field"+ intId + "\"/>");
        fieldWrapper.data("idx", intId);

        var layer_1 = $("<label ">Package "+intId+" </label>");
        var layer_2 = $("<input name=\"price[]\" type=\"number\" />");
        var layer_3 = $("<select name=\"pax[]\"><option value=\"2\">2</value><option value=\"3\">3</value><option value=\"4\">4</value></select>");
        var layer_4 = $("<select name=\"days[]\"><option value=\"2\">2 days</option><option value=\"3\">3 days</option><option value=\"4\">4 days</option></select>");
        var layer_5 = $("<input name=\"hidden[]\" type=\"hidden\" value\="+intId+"\ />");

        var removeButton = $("<input type=\"button\" value=\"X\" />");

        removeButton.click(function() {
            $(this).parent().remove();
        });
        fieldWrapper.append(layer_1);
        fieldWrapper.append(layer_2);
        fieldWrapper.append(layer_3);
        fieldWrapper.append(layer_4);
        fieldWrapper.append(layer_5);
        fieldWrapper.append(removeButton);
        $("#buildyourform").append(fieldWrapper);
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I am getting your question right, you want to print values like:

```
for($i=0; $i<count($_POST['price']); $i++){
   $price = $_POST['price'][$i];
   $pax   = $_POST['pax'][$i];
   $days  = $_POST['days'][$i];

   echo "$price  $pax  $days <br/>";
}
```

Comment: yes, I want to print values price[0] pax[0] days[0] and then price[1] pax[1] days[1] and so on. I'm sorry, but that didn't work it became an endless loop.

Comment: Oh sorry I think the reason it did not work is because I skipped $i++ in  the for loop. Let me try to to update

Comment: Whoa its working! This was my problem since yesterday and i really can't move on until I make it work hahahaha but now its working thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Try below one

```
$a = array(0, 1, 2);
$b = array(0, 1, 2);
$c = array(0, 1, 2);

for ($i = 0; $i < count($a); $i++) {
    echo $a[$i] . $b[$i] . $c[$i];    
    echo '<br/>';
}
```

Hope it will help you.